# Закрывает второе окно приложения сразу же после открытия

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Открываю по нажатии кнопки второе окно, но оно сразу же закрывается. 
В чем дело?

```
def form_settings_open(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        widget.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что `widget` это локальная переменная, которая удаляется сборщиком мусора. Продлите ей жизнь, сделайте ее атрибутом класса.

```
def form_settings_open(self):
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.widget.show()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @helldrg пожалуйста.